# What value need to pass.?http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation {


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",[address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

CLLocationCoordinate2D which fetch current location latitude and longitude.

now what need to pass in address value.....

what should be that string value.

which is equal to http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv

i want to know what will be the q=?

do i need to pass current location or designation location.

Comment: I dont know what need to pass...... I am new to iphone map controller

Comment: I think you can pass any location for which you want to get the coordinates.

Comment: actually i don't know what this url work for. if you have any idea please can you tell me why to use this url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can pass any location (any part of the address, city, street) for which you want to get the coordinates.

For example,

`q = Chennai` or `q = Adyar`